# exchange 2010 installation fails on hub transport role

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

### im installing exchange 2010 into a/d with an existing 07 installation

1. im on a 64 bit server
2. winodows 2008 R2
3. 8gb ram
4. All proper subnets are configured in the sties and services
5. all domains are raised to a server 2008 functionality level.
6. Logged on as the domain admin (schema admin, enterprise admin, etc.)
7. Range setup /PrepareSchema, setup /PrepareAD, setup /PrepareDomain, no errors
8. DCDIAG /A and DCDIAG /E show no errors
9. All readiness checks passed seccesfully, no problems
10. Double checked all PREREQS

i have it automatically install roles needed for exchange 2010

i have watched a couple video instructions on the installation and tried to see if im missing anything, everything looks fine.

whenever the exchange 2010 installation reaches the 'hub transport role, it keeps increasing the timeout and then fails to start the service. after it fails, I can start the service manually however.

### Here is the LOGGED error:

```
[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0006] [1] Processing component 'Active Directory Topology Service Configuration' (Configuring Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service).

[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0006] [1] Executing: 
          if ($exsSid -eq $null -or $exsSid -eq "")
          {
          $exsSid = get-ExchangeServerGroupSID -DomainController $RoleDomainController
          }
          start-setupservice -ServiceName MSExchangeADTopology -ServiceParameters $exsSid,$RoleDomainController


[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0006] [2] Active Directory session settings for 'start-SetupService' are: View Entire Forest: 'True', Configuration Domain Controller: 'WIN2K8DC1.JEWELS.LOCAL', Preferred Global Catalog: 'WIN2K8DC1.JEWELS.LOCAL', Preferred Domain Controllers: '{ WIN2K8DC1.JEWELS.LOCAL }'

[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0006] [2] Beginning processing start-setupservice -ServiceName:'MSExchangeADTopology' -ServiceParameters:'S-1-5-21-2134851818-3285922005-2538191131-3616','WIN2K8DC1.JEWELS.LOCAL'

[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0037] [2] Service checkpoint has progressed. Previous checkpoint='0' - Current checkpoint='1'.

[03/17/2011 18:18:56.0037] [2] Will wait '30000' milliseconds for the service 'MSExchangeADTopology' to reach status 'Running'.

[03/17/2011 18:19:26.0270] [2] Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server after waiting for '30000' milliseconds.

[03/17/2011 18:19:26.0270] [2] Service checkpoint has progressed. Previous checkpoint='1' - Current checkpoint='2'.

[03/17/2011 18:19:26.0270] [2] Will wait '1250000' milliseconds for the service 'MSExchangeADTopology' to reach status 'Running'.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server after waiting for '1250000' milliseconds.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] Service Control Manager reports no process ID for service MSExchangeADTopology.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] Unable to get the process ID for service MSExchangeADTopology because another similar process 0 was found

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] [ERROR] Unexpected Error

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] [ERROR] Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [2] Ending processing start-setupservice

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [1] The following 1 error(s) occurred during task execution:

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [1] 0.  ErrorRecord: Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0425] [1] 0.  ErrorRecord: 
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ServiceDidNotReachStatusException: Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.
[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0441] [1] [ERROR] The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
          if ($exsSid -eq $null -or $exsSid -eq "")
          {
          $exsSid = get-ExchangeServerGroupSID -DomainController $RoleDomainController
          }
          start-setupservice -ServiceName MSExchangeADTopology -ServiceParameters $exsSid,$RoleDomainController
        " was run: "Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.".

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0441] [1] [ERROR] Service 'MSExchangeADTopology' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0441] [1] [ERROR-REFERENCE] Id=AllADRolesCommonServiceControl___e95681b135f04f6ca85c706536bfbeed Component=EXCHANGE14:\Current\Release\Shared\Datacenter\Setup

[03/17/2011 18:40:16.0441] [1] Setup is stopping now because of one or more critical errors.
```

Help is appreciated :|

Comment: Since the service failed to start, there might be more information in the Windows event log about why that happened; can you check for anything useful in there?

Comment: Process ExSetupUI.exe (PID=4292). An remote procedure call (RPC) request to the Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service failed with error 1753 (Error 0x6d9 (There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper) from HrGetServersForRole). Make sure that the Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service is running. In addition, make sure that the network ports that are used by RPC are not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Maybe this book can help http://www.simple-talk.com/books/sysadmin-books/exchange-2010---a-practical-approach/

Comment: i actually purchased and watched the trainsignal.com exchange 2010 training, i'll give the e-book a look though and see if it provides anything. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this issue twice before with two different causes:

1. All IPv6 adapters were disabled.
   Enabling IPV6 on a NIC fixed it.
2. The server wasn't in the Exchange
   Domain Servers group

After making sure both of these are good, you need to delete the Watermark and Action entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\v8.0\Hub Transport` and reboot before trying setup again:

No guarantees that one of these is the answer, but it's a start.

Comment: ipv6 is enabled on the NIC. should I set an IPv6 address?

Comment: I didn't need to. This just may not be what's causing your problem if it didn't fix it :-(

Comment: im thinking about unjoining it from the domain, reinstalling everything, and trying this again. Not sure if the will cause problems the previous prepschema, prepad, and prepdomain however

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well rebuild the OS from scratch as well. Either way, you might see issues with residual or abandoned Exchange objects on the Domain afterwards. I've heard that if you run setup with "/m:RecoverServer", then it will try and detect the server's previous named Exchange objects and reinstall based upon those.

Comment: @Hyppy thats what i was planning on doing - starting fresh with the server. Do you know if with the /m:recoverserver if I need to keep the fqdn the same (win2kk8ex10.domain.local) or should i change it? (win2k8ex2)

Comment: Yes, it has to be the exact same server name with the same drive layout.

Comment: well - after a new server install, all prereqs completed and server roles setup manually. the setup still fails on the exact same step. completely stumped with this

Comment: wait, i just got it passed the exchange transport role. your answer was right, i was looking at the members of wrong. it was listed in exchange servers, however it was not listed in exchange domain servers. i added that member shit, manually started the mxexchange topology, and the role installed sucessfully. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear it ended up being a simple answer and not a complicated AD hack.

Comment: Just an FYI, this is true for me also. Membership of Exchange Domain servers = Exchange servers, but the server wasn't in either of those. I added it to the Exchange servers group and viola, works wonderfully. Thanks for the Post :) Really saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Ivp6 on the Nic that might have worked but after I turned on the Windows Firewall then re installed the Hub Transport install it did work. Thanks again...
Leo...

Answer (score 0):

I am migrating exchange 2007 to 2016 today. The path was 2007 --> 2010 --> 2016.

I had the exact same problem, so I compared group membership of 2007 server and 2010 server. I found that 2007 is in "Exchange Enterprise Servers" group but not in "Exchange Domain Servers" group. 
Furthermore, "Exchange Domain Servers" is member of "Exchange Enterprise Servers" group.

So  adding exchange2010 to "Exchange Domain Servers" group will inherit permission from "Exchange Enterprise Servers" group also.
Somehow exchange2007 is not required to be in "Exchange Domain Servers" group, but has been running without any problem for 10 year now.